# Filter an array of objects via another integer array

Tags: javascript

I have an **array of objects** that I get from an ajax call, each object has properties like in this example:

**Name:** Bob Dylan

**Value:** 452342

I also have an **inclusion array** of values, that if not empty I need to filter the **array of objects** above to contain only the ones with values from the **inclusion array**.

Update: Example of inclusion array is simply: [452342, 4563546,34563,34563456,345634]

My best guess was to have 2 loops, outer one going through the array of objects and inner one checking if they exist in the inclusion list, and if not slicing that object. Is there a better, less laborious way of doing this?

Comment: can you provide an example of what does contains your inclusion array ?

Comment: Arrays have a `.filter` method, you can use `.includes` (or `.indexOf` if you're on old browsers and/or don't want to polyfill) to check for membership in the other array after `.map`ing to a property.

Comment: Does the inclusion array contain the same object references than the array of objects? Or only objects which look like the same?

Comment: Providing a sample of the actual return data would be very helpful in being able to successfully answer your question.

Comment: Updated with example of inclusion array, changed some wording to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array.filter method and then the filter method.

```
function isInInclusion(value) {
  var inclusionArray = [2, 130, 12];
  return inclusionArray.indexOf(value) >= 0;
};

var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isInInclusion);
```

Here you have some references depends what you're using (jquery, mootools, and so on) : [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)

Comment: This answer is the closest, I was able to get this to work by replacing [12, 5, 8, 130, 44] with my array of objects and changing return inclusionArray.indexOf(value) >= 0; to return inclusionArray.indexOf(value.Value) >= 0;

Comment: Of course. I provided you an example as i didn't know your data structure.